# MySQL Create a Find and Replace Lookup Table

Tags: php, mysql

I need to create a way to automatically shorten certain values in a table in MySQL.

What I would like to do is create a table which will have three columns. The 'Original Value' and 'New Value' and an ID. Then use a query to check if a column in 'Table_A' exists in this 'Original Value' and change it to the corresponding 'New Value'.

The query I've used to find out if the value exists:

```
SELECT EXISTS (SELECT Reference FROM table_a) FROM value_lookup WHERE Original_Value != '';
```

Lets say 'Reference' contains 'This is a value'. 'Original_Value' contains 'This is a value' and 'New Value' contains 'Value'.

How can I now copy the 'New Value' to the 'Reference' in Table_A?

The only way I can think of is by selecting the new value where ID = x and copying it into reference in table_a where ID = y. But it doesn't seem the most efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Databases, it can be much more efficient to just do the operation in bulk.
Your problem statement is that you want to replace the `original value` in some table (let us call it `source`) with `new value` in some other table (let us call it `lookup`) where the `reference_value` in lookup table matches the original table.

That would translate to the following SQL statement:

```
update source a
    left join lookup b on
       a.originalValue = b.referenceValue
set
    a.originalValue = b.newValue
where 
    a.originalValue != b.newValue
```

I am not 100% sure of mysql syntax, but I hope you get the gist. Databases are usually very adept at such operations, so performance should not be a problem as well.

You can of course alter the clauses to fit your needs, for e.x. case insensitive match with Lookup, ignoring null values etc.